# Fit StandardScaler API with training data and only transform the test set with the same parameters (losing model generalization)

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, feature-scaling

If the standard scaler is better than the min max normalizer in terms of model generalization, since the standard deviation and mean are not the same for every attribute and can vary for different sets of data, and it doesn’t restricts new data to the same exact range interval, why does the transformations should only fit to the training data, to store the mean and standard deviation, to then transform the unseen test set with the same parameters? This will give also biased results on model evaluation, or not?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: check: https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/scale-training-test.html

Comment: Thank you @JulioJesus! It really helped that example.